# Dart TouchEvent.supported during emulation

Tags: dart, chromium, dart-html

`TouchEvent.supported` attempts to create a `TouchEvent` to determine touch support.  This works for actual touch devices, however, it does not help when using Chromium DevTools: “Emulate Touch Screen“.  Chromium does expose functions `Touch()` and `TouchList()` on the window object. I added a check for `context['Touch']` that now shows `supportsTouchEvent: true`.  It is still not an indicator of whether “Emulate Touch Screen” is active. Any suggestions appreciated!

```dart
//bool get supportsTouchEvents =>TouchEvent.supported;
bool get supportsTouchEvents {
  bool bIsTouchSupported = TouchEvent.supported;
  if (bIsTouchSupported == false) {
     //Get the browser's native window and check for Touch function
     JsObject nativeTouch = context['Touch'];
     bIsTouchSupported = (nativeTouch is JsObject);
     //Check Chromium DevTools "Emulate Touch Screen"
  }
  return bIsTouchSupported;
}
```

Update-1: The additional check for context['Touch'] function does provide more insight that touch handling is possible. But it's a false-positive due to "Emulation" is not active until the DevTools window is opened. As a bloated alternative: If nativeTouch install both mouse and touch streamcontrollers/handlers.

Comment: @Günter: Thanks! I should have referenced it in the original post. The issue still is "Defect-Unassigned", I was hoping to stimulate other alternatives and ideas here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This is a know bug ...............................

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16669

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I appreciate your research effort but I hope by now you must have realized that your answer has been flagged for its content and length. Perhaps you could have put this link in a comment. What are you providing the OP apart from a link in an answer?

Comment: @Rachcha This is not a link-only answer. It contains two valuable pieces of information: that the observed behavior is a bug in dart (as opposed to a bug in the posted code, or a misunderstanding in how the API should behave, or a bug in Chrome, etc.), and that this bug has already been reported and tracked. See [the meta thread about this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228190/how-to-handle-link-only-bug-report-answers-that-are-perhaps-the-only-correct-an/228254#228254).